# XPath 1.0 comparison of NaN and any other value

Tags: xpath, nan, xpath-1.0

I'm learning about XML and XPath in my university course (XPath 1.0 to be exact) and I stumbled upon something. F.e. if I write an expression:

```
NaN < true()
```

it returns true. Which is very weird. When I do.

`NaN < 1`

it returns false. AFAIK XPath 1.0 comparisons (without node-sets) first convert the values to numbers and only then compares them. So, in the first expression it goes like this

`NaN < number(true())` -> `NaN < 1`

and in the second

`NaN < 1`

I'd like to get to the bottom of this, so any information would be helpful. I didn't find anything concerning this situation in the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/). Maybe I missed something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token NaN does not represent the double value NaN, it is short for `child::NaN` which returns an empty node-set (unless of course your XML document contains an element named NaN).

I'm a little surprised that a university should be teaching XPath 1.0 which has long been superseded by new versions. Of course lots of people are still using it, but I would have thought a university would teach a newer version.

Comment: Got it. How would a double value NaN be written then? And also, just because maybe you'd know, how would the number value infinity would be written in 1.0? About the second part: tell me about it. The professor's reasoning was that 1.0 is still the most widely adopted version. We'll be learning jQuery down the road too, which is quite old (but widely used for legacy systems) too.

Comment: Good, but  why would `NaN < 1` evaluate to false per OP's second example?

Comment: `NaN < 1` and `NaN > 1` and `NaN < true()` and `NaN > true()` all evaluate to `false` using BaseX 9.4 command line. Compiling for last expression: **Compiling:**
`- remove step without results: *:NaN`
`- rewrite cached step to empty sequence: *:NaN -> ()`
`- rewrite cached path to empty sequence: db:open-pre("my", 0)/() -> ()`
`- rewrite fn:true() to xs:boolean item: true()`
`- rewrite empty sequence to xs:boolean item: () -> false()`
`- rewrite fn:boolean(items) to xs:boolean item: boolean(()) -> false()`
`- rewrite > comparison to xs:boolean item: () > true() -> false()`

Comment: @user18451290 isn't this based on XQuery 3.1, which (I'd guess) is not based on XPath 1.0 in which I'm interested in?

Comment: @Kibartas Maybe it will be useful later when your teacher asks you why `NaN < true()` evaluates to `false` with XPath 3.0.

Comment: The XPath 1.0 rule for comparing a node-set with a boolean is that an empty node-set is treated as false, a non-empty node-set as true; and false is less than true. When comparing a node-set with a number, the node-set is converted to a number, and the conversion yields NaN if the node-set is empty: so in the context of a numeric comparison, NaN denotes `child::NaN` which is typically an empty node-set, which on conversion to a number delivers the value NaN.

Comment: @Kibertas there are many ways of writing a constant NaN but the clearest is probably `number("NaN")`. If I remember right (it's a long time since I used XPath 1.0), positive infinity is written as `1 div 0`, though that's not ideal because it's not forward compatible to 2.0; if you want a forward compatible construct, try `number(1) div number(0)`.